# Why does the number of question views round up?

Tags: discussion, bug, views

I saw this today:

[image]

Why does this happen? Is there a reasonable answer or is it just the designer's choice?

Comment: Can you give a reason for rounding it down rather than rounding it up?

Comment: so I can track my post views like milestones. this way I get confused. If it rounds down I Always know that I certainly hit that. there is a badge for number of views and it can be confusing if it rounds up.

Comment: These views aren't an _exact_ science, though. It's just a number that's more related to page loads than actual views...

Comment: I can somewhat understand OPs point as the round-up here is almost 25%. 1.6K would have made more sense. Rounding(up or down depending on the situation) to the nearest multiple of 100/1000/1m would have made more sense instead of rounding up all the time.

Comment: @PavanManjunath Then should 1.740.000 be rounded to 1.75m?

Comment: @Cerbrus maybe it is better because it is less than 1% difference.

Comment: @MahdiJoon: No, as 1.74m would be an exact match...

Comment: The point is the rounding strategy some times has a lot of difference than the actual number. if 2.040.000 rounds to 2m or 2.1m it is only 2%-3% but 1.6k to 2k is 25%.

Comment: @MahdiJoon: rounding between 2m or 2.1m is a difference of 500.000 views, while 2k is, at most, a difference of 500. Percentages are misleading if you change the order of magnitude like that.

Comment: It is 50.000 difference and I don't say it like that. I will say 2.5% difference. After all as I mentioned before maybe it's just a matter of style. I still disagree with the way it is now though. @Cerbrus

Comment: Cross-site dupe on MSE: [Error rounding up number of views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109559/241919) (by design since 2011)

Answer (score 5):

That's just for readability.

Large numbers like that aren't necessarily "useful", especially when they get really big:

[image: Example of a question's view count, showing how "1,679,203" gets displayed as "1.7m"]

In your example, 1613 is being rounded to the *nearest* full thousand, which is 2000.

Comment: As I commented on the question I think it will be better if it rounds down. because if it shows 1.6m it is true. the post has 1679203 views but if it shows 1.7m it is not true logically.

Comment: So, what if the question has 1999 views? Should it still be rounded down to 1k then, @MahdiJoon? That makes no sense.

Comment: 1679203 isn't any more equal to 1.6m than to 1.7m. "because if it shows 1.6m it is true." only applies to your specific use case, not in general.

Comment: hmmm... I didn't convinced though. Maybe it is just a matter of style. some prefer round up some don't.

Comment: @MahdiJoon, let me rephrase the question: If there are `1999` views, what _should_ be shown? `1k`? `2k`?

Comment: That wasn't a "yes/no" question...

Comment: I thought you want to edit the title. :)

Comment: What? No... I asked you how _you_ think `1999` _should_ be rounded, instead?

Comment: Tab vs spaces. Round-up vs round-down. Easy life choices ...

Comment: I mean, sure, it's for readablity, but this is inconsistent with other areas. For example, all question lists break rep down to the nearest 100 once above 1k, so someone with 1.6k rep would see 1.6k, not 2k. there's certainly enough room to break it down to 1.6k rather than 2k, or to even not round at all until 10k

Answer (score -2):

I agree that it's sad about this very high rounds up.

For me, it should be showed as `1.6k` instead of `2k` mainly because it's too far. from the original, and will change from 1k to 2k instantly after reaching 1 501.

It's not too long because for millions it will be `2.4m`, and here it's the same amount of chars.

Comment: I think the reason for this can be nicely covered by the fact that the (absolute) difference between 1.5k and 2k is _far_ less than the difference between 2,500,000 and 3,000,000

Comment: Yes, but not in porcent, and treat a little question as very big one isn't good idea

Comment: Changing something here does not change anything about how sad the number is though, because whatever you do it remains a lie.

Comment: @Gimby the objective is to not "so much" lie. Increase of 25% the amount if not normal, but increase around 5% it's ok. Also, I'm running the same issue, one of my question is showed as 2k but with 1503 views... So it's too much lie comparing to "1k5" as showing value

Comment: @Elikill58 nothing changes about the fact the views are not actual proven views.